# How to call a custom terraform provider from a terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to write a terraform module which will take one parameter as input and generate tags like: `Team`, `Slack`, `Environment` based on the input. This input will be used to invoke REST api and get values of Team, Slack etc.

I was thinking of writing a custom terraform provider which will invoke the REST api. But I am not sure how to call the custom provider from terraform module.

Answer (score 0):

I found a provider for rest api.
https://github.com/Mastercard/terraform-provider-restapi
You can use it or create new one referring to it.

You can refer to https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#third-party-plugins for 3rd plugin installation